# Storing multiple objects in chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am building a chrome extension in which I fetch data from an API and I want to make different objects of the data and then store it in chrome storage. 
For example :-

```
data:[
    {
     name:"XYZ",
     URL:"xyz.com"
   },
   {
     name:"ABC",
     URL:"abc.com"
   }
]
```

I want to store the returned data from the API in the chrome storage as different objects.

I tried doing the following but it didn't work:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ name: 'xyz', URL: "xyz.com" });

chrome.storage.sync.set({ name: 'abc', URL:"abc.com" });

 chrome.storage.sync.get(['name'], (result) => {
    console.log(result.name);
  });
```

I am getting the result as only the second object I stored I tried directly passing the objects as well but it doesn't seem to work. 
Is there any way to store the data in different objects and an effective way to retrieve all the data separately?

Comment: The syntax is `chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}`

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: The entire storage is just like an object so each key corresponds to a value. For example you can do set({xyz: 'xyz.com', abc: 'abc.com'})